# How to force a device to enumerate as different class USB device?

Tags: usb

I purchased an inexpensive RFID reader. If works great with my Ubuntu box, with one exception. It enumerates as a HID device, and more specifically USB keyboard. That is, if I have a console open and swipe a card, in the console the number of the card, followed by a newline, get typed.

I could `tail -f > logfile` this, but am worried by the security implications. This guy could `ctrl + alt + T` at any moment and have the full permissions as my user has.

Is there a way to tell the kernel that when it sees this manufacturer id + device id, to not trust it's descriptors and instead enumerate it as storage device, e.g. `/dev/sdd`?

Comment: If I understand you, you're worried about someone who could spy on your machine, to read your RFID card details when you scan it, and then replay those details in order to login as you?

Comment: @fduff, no, I am afraid that the firmware of the RFID reader could type `wget http://grlorious-trojan` while I am not looking.